# How to stop my panolens.js image from pausing spinning whenever the user clicks on it?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a 360 image background that automatically rotates which it is doing and I also prevented the user from having any camera controls but the one thing I can't figure out is how to prevent the user from having any interaction with whatsoever. The only thing I can't seem to stop is that whenever the user clicks on the background image that's spinning the picture pauses for about 3 seconds and then starts spinning again, I'm not sure if there's a function or way to stop this.

```
const panoramaImage = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama("img/ship.jpeg");
const imageContainer = document.querySelector(".image-container");

const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({
    container: imageContainer,
    autoRotate: true,
    autoRotateSpeed: 0.3,
    controlBar: false
});

viewer.OrbitControls.noRotate = true;
viewer.OrbitControls.noZoom = true;
viewer.OrbitControls.noPan = true;


viewer.add(panoramaImage);
viewer.onWindowResize();
```

This is my js code.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation [`PANOLENS.Viewer`](https://pchen66.github.io/panolens.js/docs/Viewer.html)

- You can see that there is a [`Viewer.disableAutoRate()`](https://pchen66.github.io/panolens.js/docs/Viewer.html#disableAutoRate) to disable auto rotation.
- Also a [`Viewer.enableAutoRate()`](https://pchen66.github.io/panolens.js/docs/Viewer.html#enableAutoRate) to enable it.
- From there you can implement a function that disable it and with a `setTimeout` that enable it again.
- Controls are defined with an [`THREE.OrbitControls`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) if you check the [source code](https://pchen66.github.io/panolens.js/docs/viewer_Viewer.js.html).
  Meaning that if for example you want to disable pan interaction you can toggle pan with [`OrbitControls.enablePan()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.enablePan).